# Why can't I select specific columns from collection using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, ef-code-first

using the lambda expression I just want to select 2 columns but it throws error.

Code:

```
 public List<Certificates> GetClientsList(string certificationNo = "")
        {
            List<Certificates> certificatesList = new List<Certificates>();
            var query = uow.CertificatesRepository.GetQueryable().AsQueryable();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificationNo))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.CertificationNo.Contains(certificationNo)).Select(n => new { ClientName= n.Client, ID= n.CertificatesID});
            }
            certificatesList = query.ToList();

            return certificatesList;
        }
```

Certificates class:

```
public class Certificates
    {
        public int CertificatesID { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Certification No")]
        public string CertificationNo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Issue Date")]
        public string IssueDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Details { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Client { get; set; }
    }
```

Error:

Cannot convert Anonymous querable type to List

Comment: You are projecting to an anonymous type `new { ClientName= n.Client, ID= n.CertificatesID}` and trying to mash it in to a `List` of `Certificates`. also this looks suspect `.GetQueryable().AsQueryable()` Also you are using the repository pattern over *EntityFramework*, but ill hold my tongue there

Comment: The error is saying you’re returning an anonymous type from the query but you want to put it in a list, which can only handle actual types. And your list even expects a very specific type. So you should return objects of that type.

Comment: first - change the var declaration to the explicit type to see what's happening.  2nd change the class name to singular `Certificate` to stop confusion reigning

Comment: Can you try that? `var result = query.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();` And you cannot return List<Certificates> because after select you have an anonymus type.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this (depending on the return type of `CertificatesRepository`)

```
public List<Certificates> GetClientsList(string certificationNo = "")
{
   var query = uow.CertificatesRepository;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificationNo))
      return query.ToList();

   return query.Where(x => x.CertificationNo.Contains(certificationNo))
               .ToList();
}
```

**Update**

> The thing is want is to select 2 columns only

```
public List<Certificates> GetClientsList(string certificationNo = "")
{
   var query = uow.CertificatesRepository;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificationNo))
      return query.Select(n => new Certificates { ClientName = n.Client, ID = n.CertificatesID})
                  .ToList();

   return query.Where(x => x.CertificationNo.Contains(certificationNo))
               .Select(n => new Certificates { ClientName = n.Client, ID = n.CertificatesID})
               .ToList();
}
```

or

```
public List<(int ID , string ClientName)> GetClientsList(string certificationNo = "")
{
   var query = uow.CertificatesRepository;

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificationNo))
      return query.Select(n => (ID = n.CertificatesID, ClientName = n.Client))
                  .ToList();

   return query.Where(x => x.CertificationNo.Contains(certificationNo))
               .Select(n => (ID = n.CertificatesID, ClientName = n.Client))
               .ToList();
}
```

Comment: The thing is want is to select 2 columns only.

Comment: @CodingManiac So you dont want to use your Certificates class in the results

Comment: I do but only 2 columns should be selected and client should be distinct

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it converted to Queryable first? what type does uow.CertificatesRepository.GetQueryable() return?

```
public List<Certificates> GetClientsList(string certificationNo = "")
        {
            var query = uow.CertificatesRepository.GetQueryable(); // do ToList here if it is IQuerable, but as it seems it was not.

            return query.Where(x=>x.CertificationNo.Contains(certificationNo)).Select(x=> new Certificates(){ClientName= n.Client, ID= n.CertificatesID}).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: The entity or complex type 'VAILCertificates.DAL.Certificates' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: If the object has properties market as Required, and you are trying to create a Certification objct only using two fields it will fail. Or create a different object type or provide values for other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Select` returns anonymous objects. These anonymous objects of course can't be converted to Certificates.

If you really want to use your Certificates class, then you could just create new objects in your select:

```
public List<Certificates> GetClientsList(string certificationNo = "")
{
   List<Certificates> certificatesList = new List<Certificates>();
   var query = uow.CertificatesRepository.GetQueryable().AsQueryable();
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certificationNo))
   {
       query = query.Where(x => x.CertificationNo.Contains(certificationNo)).Select(n => new Certificates{ Client = n.Client, CertificatesID = n.CertificatesID});
   }
   certificatesList = query.ToList();
   return certificatesList;
}
```

A better solution would probably be to create a new class which only contains the two required properties.

A third possibility is to return a `List<dynamic>` instead. But then you are not strongly typed anymore.